# Adding new OpenShift nodes to GlusterFS

Tags: ansible, openshift, openshift-origin, glusterfs, okd

I have an OpenShift Origin 3.11 cluster installed with GlusterFS storage. It is a single master setup with my initial inventory looking like this:

```
[nodes]
console.example.com openshift_ip=1.2.3.4 openshift_schedulable=true openshift_node_group_name='node-config-all-in-one'

node-01.example.com openshift_ip=1.2.3.1 openshift_schedulable=true openshift_node_group_name='node-config-compute'

node-02.example.com openshift_ip=1.2.3.2 openshift_schedulable=true openshift_node_group_name='node-config-compute'



[glusterfs]
console.example.com glusterfs_devices='[ "/dev/sda" ]'

node-01.example.com glusterfs_devices='[ "/dev/sda" ]'

node-02.example.com glusterfs_devices='[ "/dev/sda" ]'
```

I added a new node to my cluster by modifying my inventory to:

```
[nodes]
console.example.com openshift_ip=1.2.3.4 openshift_schedulable=true openshift_node_group_name='node-config-all-in-one'

node-01.example.com openshift_ip=1.2.3.1 openshift_schedulable=true openshift_node_group_name='node-config-compute'

node-02.example.com openshift_ip=1.2.3.2 openshift_schedulable=true openshift_node_group_name='node-config-compute'



[glusterfs]
console.example.com glusterfs_devices='[ "/dev/sda" ]'

node-01.example.com glusterfs_devices='[ "/dev/sda" ]'

node-02.example.com glusterfs_devices='[ "/dev/sda" ]'

[new_nodes]
node-03.example.com openshift_ip=1.2.3.3 openshift_schedulable=true openshift_node_group_name='node-config-compute'
```

and running:

```
ansible-playbook playbooks/openshift-node/scaleup.yml
```

Which ran successfully. Now, to add this new node as a GlusterFS volume, I added this node to the `glusterfs` group,

```
[nodes]
console.example.com openshift_ip=1.2.3.4 openshift_schedulable=true openshift_node_group_name='node-config-all-in-one'

node-01.example.com openshift_ip=1.2.3.1 openshift_schedulable=true openshift_node_group_name='node-config-compute'

node-02.example.com openshift_ip=1.2.3.2 openshift_schedulable=true openshift_node_group_name='node-config-compute'
node-03.example.com openshift_ip=1.2.3.3 openshift_schedulable=true openshift_node_group_name='node-config-compute'



[glusterfs]
console.example.com glusterfs_devices='[ "/dev/sda" ]'

node-01.example.com glusterfs_devices='[ "/dev/sda" ]'

node-02.example.com glusterfs_devices='[ "/dev/sda" ]'

node-03.example.com  glusterfs_devices='[ "/dev/sda" ]'

[new_nodes]
```

and ran the corresponding playbook,

```
ansible-playbook playbooks/openshift-glusterfs/config.yml
```

but this fails in the

```
TASK [openshift_storage_glusterfs : Wait for GlusterFS pods] *******************
```

step. Am I missing running any other playbook?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, `converged mode` are not supported extension by `ansible` playbooks.
Because the `heketi` initialization of the disk devices are supported at that time during only clean installation, so you'd like to extend the existing `glusterfs` cluster, then 
manual operations are required as shown this:[12.1.3. Adding a New Cluster](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_gluster_storage/3.3/html-single/container-native_storage_for_openshift_container_platform/#idm139668592910240).